# Please how do i handle this error "Unhandled Rejection (Type Error): Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-static-web-app

I need your help.
I am a newbie with javascript/React.
I am working on this tutorial https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-client-cognitive-services and I get this error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined".
[Attached is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqZsC.png)

Responses will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the variable `analysis.tags` is undefined.

You can use `console.log(analysis)` to checkout the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add check on tags object before doing any action

```
tags && tags.filter(your remaining code)
```